# How to change the bool expand in State of class?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to access the update method from outside? I need to change `expand` because this is in a `ListView` and if it is focused i want to change stuff like color and size(which is not yet implemented).
Anybody know how to do this?
And maybe if you know is there a widget which changes the size of its child not height and width but like zoom? So that all its children get bigger by a factor.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tastie/models/Cuisine.dart';
import 'package:tastie/models/Restaurant.dart';
import 'package:tastie/style.dart';

class RestaurantPreview extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext context;
  final Restaurant resto;

  RestaurantPreview(this.context, this.resto);

  @override
  _RestaurantPreviewState createState() => _RestaurantPreviewState(false);
}

class _RestaurantPreviewState extends State<RestaurantPreview> {
  bool expand;

  void update(bool x) {
    setState(() {
      expand = x;
    });
  }
  _RestaurantPreviewState(this.expand);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: expand ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.6,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              //image of restaurnt via id
              Flex(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.resto.name,
                      style: Style.homeFeedTextStyleName,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                    child: Image(
                      image: widget.resto.logo.image,
                      height: Style.homeFeedTextStyleName.fontSize *
                          (MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor + 0.4),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Style.homeFeedRadius),
                child: widget.resto.image,
              ),
              Text(
                widget.resto.description,
                style: Style.homeFeedTextStyleDescription,
              ),
              Wrap(
                spacing: 5.0,
                alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  for (int cuisine in widget.resto.cuisines)
                    Chip(
                      label: Text(Cuisine.getName(cuisine)),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use `GlobalKey` to get `_RestaurantPreviewState` and call `update` function

```
GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

RestaurantPreview(
              key: _key,
              context: context,
              resto: Restaurant(
                  name: "name",
                  logoImage: "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9",
                  image: "https://picsum.photos/250?image=10",
                  description: "desc",
                  cuisines: ["1", "2", "3"]),
            ),
RaisedButton(
              child: Text('expand true'),
              onPressed: () {
                final _RestaurantPreviewState previewState = _key.currentState;
                previewState.update(true);
              },
            ),
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Restaurant {
  String name;
  String logoImage;
  String image;
  String description;
  List<String> cuisines;

  Restaurant(
      {this.name, this.logoImage, this.image, this.description, this.cuisines});
}

class RestaurantPreview extends StatefulWidget {
  final BuildContext context;
  final Restaurant resto;

  RestaurantPreview({Key key, this.context, this.resto}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RestaurantPreviewState createState() => _RestaurantPreviewState(false);
}

class _RestaurantPreviewState extends State<RestaurantPreview> {
  bool expand;

  void update(bool x) {
    setState(() {
      expand = x;
    });
  }

  _RestaurantPreviewState(this.expand);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: expand ? Colors.red : Colors.white,
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(
            maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.6,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              //image of restaurnt via id
              Flex(
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 4),
                    child: Text(
                      widget.resto.name,
                      //style: Style.homeFeedTextStyleName,
                    ),
                  ),
                  ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2),
                    child: Image(
                      image: NetworkImage(widget.resto.logoImage),
                      height: 100,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                child: Image.network(widget.resto.image),
              ),
              Text(
                widget.resto.description,
                //style: Style.homeFeedTextStyleDescription,
              ),
              Wrap(
                spacing: 5.0,
                alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                direction: Axis.horizontal,
                children: [
                  for (String cuisine in widget.resto.cuisines)
                    Chip(
                      label: Text("$cuisine"),
                    )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey _key = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            RestaurantPreview(
              key: _key,
              context: context,
              resto: Restaurant(
                  name: "name",
                  logoImage: "https://picsum.photos/250?image=9",
                  image: "https://picsum.photos/250?image=10",
                  description: "desc",
                  cuisines: ["1", "2", "3"]),
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('expand true'),
              onPressed: () {
                final _RestaurantPreviewState previewState = _key.currentState;
                previewState.update(true);
              },
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('expand false'),
              onPressed: () {
                final _RestaurantPreviewState previewState = _key.currentState;
                previewState.update(false);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much